# callbacks in keras gives KeyError: 'metrics' while predict

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am getting the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-254-f01ba8163f7d> in <module>
      1 out_batch = NBatchLogger(display=1000)
      2 model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=250,verbose = 0,
----> 3              callbacks=[out_batch])

1 frames
<ipython-input-247-55bb2505c62e> in on_batch_end(self, batch, logs)
     14     def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
     15         self.step += 1
---> 16         for k in self.params['metrics']:
     17             if k in logs:
     18                 self.metric_cache[k] = self.metric_cache.get(k, 0) + logs[k]

KeyError: 'metrics
```

Here is my code:

```
 class PrintProgress(keras.callbacks.Callback):
      def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        if epoch % 100 == 0: print('Epoch', epoch)
            
    class NBatchLogger(keras.callbacks.Callback):
        """
        A Logger that log average performance per `display` steps.
        """
        def __init__(self, display):
            self.step = 0
            self.display = display
            self.metric_cache = {}
    
        def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
            self.step += 1
            for k in self.params['metrics']:
                if k in logs:
                    self.metric_cache[k] = self.metric_cache.get(k, 0) + logs[k]
            if self.step % self.display == 0:
                metrics_log = ''
                for (k, v) in self.metric_cache.items():
                    val = v / self.display
                    if abs(val) > 1e-3:
                        metrics_log += ' - %s: %.4f' % (k, val)
                    else:
                        metrics_log += ' - %s: %.4e' % (k, val)
                print('step: {}/{} ... {}'.format(self.step,
                                              self.params['steps'],
                                              metrics_log))
                self.metric_cache.clear()
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session(
)
```

When trying to compute confusion matrix

```py
confusion_matrix(np.argmax(Y_train, axis = 1), pred_train)
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback's params only have values used in fit call (in this case verbose, epochs and steps). If you want to access model's metrics from within callback, you need to set the model for callback with

```py
out_batch.set_model(model)
```

And then access it with `self.model.metrics` inside callback's method.

Here is your Callback implementation with fixes:

```py
class NBatchLogger(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    """
    A Logger that log average performance per `display` steps.
    """
    def __init__(self, display):
        self.step = 0
        self.display = display
        self.metric_cache = {}

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        self.step += 1
        for k in self.model.metrics:
            if k.name not in self.metric_cache.keys():
                self.metric_cache[k.name] = 0.0
            self.metric_cache[k.name] += logs.get(k.name)
        if self.step % self.display == 0:
            metrics_log = ''
            for (k, v) in self.metric_cache.items():
                val = v / self.display
                if abs(val) > 1e-3:
                    metrics_log += ' - %s: %.4f' % (k, val)
                else:
                    metrics_log += ' - %s: %.4e' % (k, val)
            print('step: {}/{} ... {}'.format(self.step,
                                          self.params['steps'],
                                          metrics_log))
            self.metric_cache.clear()
```

And output I got:

```py
step: 10/240 ...  - loss: 2.2448 - accuracy: 0.2207
step: 20/240 ...  - loss: 2.0735 - accuracy: 0.3876
step: 30/240 ...  - loss: 1.8155 - accuracy: 0.4899
step: 40/240 ...  - loss: 1.5696 - accuracy: 0.5502
step: 50/240 ...  - loss: 1.3779 - accuracy: 0.6002
step: 60/240 ...  - loss: 1.2252 - accuracy: 0.6412
```

**EDIT:**
To fix the error `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets` with confusion matrix, you should change

```py
confusion_matrix(np.argmax(y_train, axis=1), pred_train)
```

to

```py
confusion_matrix(np.argmax(y_train, axis=1), np.argmax(pred_train, axis=1))
```

because you need to convert predicted labels same way as train labels.

Comment: Thank you Maciek, After running the code i am getting problem with  Confusion Matrix. I have add code above. Please can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: @Maik looks like you tried to edit my answer instead of your post. Please add this code to question.

Comment: Yes but you also should write the code that causes the error. I edited it for you.

Comment: @Maik please do **not** edit your posts to include follow-up questions after an answer has been provided. Open a *new* question instead (it is free)!

Comment: Ok. Sure. Thank you for the replay. sorry, the late reply to you.